# my beer smells some like yeast ?!? taste ok. but smell is off? help.

Tags: yeast

my beer smell like yeast. taste is ok but there is a strong off odor.

Comment: How long ago did you brew? Do you take gravity readings? If so, what was the original, and what is it now? Is it still in a carboy, or is it packaged?

Comment: What type of yeast are you using?

Comment: what stage of life is the beer at? Is this during Primary Fermentation, Secondary, Bottling, Bulk Aging, etc?

Answer (score 3):

How long have you been brewing?  If you are new to the wonderful hobby, the smell may seem strong but is pretty normal depending on the stage of fermentation.  When I transfer my beer to the secondary, it smells very strongly of yeast but this calms down after a while.

If you have brewing for a while, then something else might be going on and I am unable to help you without more information, but if the beer tastes fine then I would say that it is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that your yeast was overactive/underused. You could try adding more sugars, but really I would just suggest giving it more time to sit. Let the yeast settle.